# Can't inject ngRoute dependency in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I can't seem to create a simple angular route in my current application, since it handles me the following error: **Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]**

I have already injected ngRoute as a dependency in my module, as well as added the angular-route.js script in my html file. My current Angular version is 1.2.25, so it's the angular-route script.

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ACME App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="init">
    <a ng-href="#main">sup</a>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

**controllers.js**

```
var app = angular.module("init", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config('$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "templates/main.html"
    });
});
```

**templates/main.html**

```
<h1>Main Page</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you missed `[ ]`

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "templates/main.html"
    });
}]);
```